# JQuery The value 'i' starts from 0 for every button in table but i need the row button onclick to start from a particular index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

The value 'i' in alert() starts from 0 for every button in table when clicked but i need the row button when clicked to start from a particular index.

Basically I think the for loop is looping from start for every button clicked.
What could be the solution? Plz suggest

```
   function sendGetData () {    
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'Refresh',
     success: function (data) {

         var trHTML = '';


         $.each(data, function (i, item) {

             if(data[i].test_progress=="Complete")
             {  

             var buttonVar = ('<button id="btn11">'+"Clicking"+'</button>');
             }
             else
                 {
             var buttonVar = ('<button id="btn12">'+"Stoping"+'</button>');
                 }


             trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[i].test_type + 
             '</td><td>' + data[i].device_id + 
             '</td><td>' + data[i].make + '&nbsp'+data[i].model+
             '</td><td>' + data[i].stack_name +
             '</td><td>' + data[i].suite_name + 
             '</td><td>' + data[i].test_progress + '<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'+data[i].tests_run+'/'+data[i].total_tests+
             '</td><td>' + data[i].start_time + 
             '</td><td>' + data[i].end_time +
             '</td><td>' + buttonVar +
             '</td></tr>';

              $(document).on('click', '#btn11', function(event) {
                 alert("The paragraph was clicked."+ i);
                });

              $(document).on('click', '#btn12', function(event) {
                 alert("The paragraph was not clicked."+i);
                });


            });
         $('#test1').append(trHTML);
         $('#test').hide();
         $('#show').show();


     }
 });
}
```

Comment: check if `i == index you want` then do something...

Comment: You creating invalid html with your duplicate `id` attributes. Use a class name instead. Are you wanting to get the index (row number) of the row that the button is in when you click it?

Comment: Yes i want index(row number) of the row when button is clicked.It is closure as mentioned by dec

Comment: Hard to be sure what your trying to do with this code, but have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9huLw0f/)

Comment: Okay Great Thanks this is what i wanted...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is generating duplicate `id` attributes for your buttons in the loop (invalid html) and your also duplicating the `$(document).on('click', ..` scripts in each iteration. Because of the invalid html, your script will only ever act on the first button with `id="btn11"`. Instead use a class name and use relative selectors to get the row number.

To dynamically add your rows

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      // initialize a row
      var row = $('<tr></tr>');
      // add table cells
      row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.test_type));
      row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.device_id));
      ....
      if (item.test_progress === 'Complete') {
        row.append($('<button></button>').text('Clicking').addClass('complete')); // add class name
      } else {
        row.append($('<button></button>').text('Stoping').addClass('notcomplete'));
      }
      // append the row
      $('#test1').append(row);
    });
  }
});
```

Then include scripts to handle each button type based on the class name

```
$('#test1').on('click', '.complete', function() {
  // Get the row number using the .index() function
  var rownum = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;
  alert("The paragraph was clicked. The row number is "+ rownum);
});
```